# Why do you allow bullying by Thomas Shultz and his gang on these forums?

Tags: discussion

I don't appreciate being bullied by a group of people who support Thomas Shultz ( and each other ) because i down vote low quality answers by them.

And i don't appreciate this gang ( because thats what they are behaving like ) joining with your staff (JNat) and trying to intimidate me to stop down voting by sending carefully worded emails and messages designed to intimidate.

Thomas Shultz has bullied me on a number of occasions on these forums and on his own Google Plus group over the last year or so. He clearly has an issue with me.

I have also received anonymous threats from different I.P addresses after down voting. If i have a problem with someone, i contact them directly to sort it out and i use my real name.

I don't hide and gather a group of people together for support to try and intimidate one person.

EDIT: Here's the email Thomas Shultz got his buddy (JNat) to send me which makes false claims against me after i down voted 3 of Thomas Shultz's answers:

**Re: WordPress Development Stack Exchange: message from moderators re account Brad Dalton**

Hello,

I'm writing in reference to your WordPress Development Stack Exchange account:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9884/brad-dalton

I wanted to let you know that we received a complaint citing rudeness from your part when contacting a user through their personal e-mail address. We get it; anyone who's ever tried to engage with others online has probably been tempted to lash out at someone else. This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to act in a professional and civil tone when using these sites, and that it is not reasonable to contact a user through their personal e-mail address regarding whatever they may have done on-site to complain. The appropriate course of action would be for you to flag the user's post for moderator attention or to contact the staff so we can have a better look at what has happened.

If this is a simple misunderstanding, no harm done. I just wanted to let you know about our take on this kind of behaviour. Sometimes it is helpful to remind ourselves on occasion that keeping things friendly and constructive doesn't have to be at odds with being right — so enjoy the site, bring your sense of humour, and please be tolerant of others.

Regards,
JNat
Community Growth Operations Specialist at Stack Exchange

**This email was sent from an unmonitored account. Do not reply directly to this email; if you feel this message is incorrect, please respond on WordPress Development Stack Exchange here.**

Comment: This sounds like an awful situation to be in. Are there any instances of being bullied here that you can link to?

Comment: Many but i'm not sure they still exist as they may have been removed.

Comment: It may be easier for people to understand the situation better if you can find instances of being bullied on here and link to them ( possibly screenshot in the case the aggressor goes back and deletes it ). I'm not entirely sure if admins can see deleted content or not.

Comment: If they have been removed, there will be a history you can link to demonstrating it, and showing what they removed. Even as a moderator if I wanted to remove something, there would be viewable history, and a high ranking user can see pretty much everything there is to see

Comment: I would also note, these aren't discussion forums, and don't follow the format the .org support forums follow

Comment: Thomas has reputation for deleting stuff. He already deleted a discussion i started on his Google Plus group and was very unfriendly and clearly didn't want me posting anything.

Comment: Your voting behavior is not related to the mod message. Insults per private email are.

Comment: @toscho The claims in the email you asked staff to send are false and designed to intimidate me into stopping down voting your answers as it came immediately after i did so. And what do you have to say about the bias attitude on your Google plus group? And the reason you deleted my post there?

Comment: All I did was forwarding your private email to the stuff. Nothing else. This is something I **have to do**. I am not allowed to perform moderation actions that aren't visible for Stack Exchange employees. This rule exists for your protection, and I will always stick to it. Google Plus is a different topic. Ask there for the reasons. I will always respond and explain each case. Keep in mind that I am not the only mod over there, and there is no history of mod actions on G+, so I might not be able to answer. Whenever I feel that *might* be biased, I leave the response to other mods.

Comment: What you did was forward my private message to you to staff so they would send me an intimidating email to try and stop me down voting your answers as this has never happened before and came immediately after i down voted 2 of your answers. Thats bullying and intimidation to try and rig the reputation points system.

Comment: Emails about SE moderation to moderators are not private at all. I am required to make that transparent for SE. I didn't even know about your downvotes, because I cannot see who is voting on my answers.

Comment: No insult intended, but oh my goodness, paranoid much? For what its worth I have got down votes and deletions on occasion too - it just happens! Aside from that the only question raised here for me is, how can I join »The Gang«? But joking aside, stay cool, calm and collected. Because anger and rage will get you nowhere in communication based systems, a common ground is a must. Or as @JonEricson said » I think it would be in your best interest to take a bit of time to let things cool off first«.

Answer (score 14):

No, we don't allow bullying. Not by anyone. Every now and then someone takes it on themselves to drive another user from the site. Vigilantism like that is caustic to a community and is a reason we have [the penalty box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

JNat contacted you this morning because of an incident brought to our attention last week. The contents of the message seem pretty clear to me, but I'd be happy to clarify anything that's confusing. As a summary, according to our [Be Nice policy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), you should contact us directly if you feel like you are the victim of bullying on the site.

Some tips to help things go more smoothly:

1. Whenever possible, **link to the incident** in question. (If it's a comment, the link is hidden behind the date field.)
2. If you can't link (often because the comment(s) are deleted) **describe the incident** in as much detail as you remember.
3. **Do not contact the other user off site.** Sometimes people take their concerns directly to the other person via email or whatnot. Unfortunately, that often comes across as threatening. If you are going to confront another user, it's generally best to use Stack Exchange chat or a meta post. But if you feel you are the victim of bullying, the [contact us form](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) is your best bet.
4. **Be aware of the bigger picture.** It's natural for people to get caught up in the moment and forget that there's are more perspectives than their own. To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_vision_(disambiguation)):

   > Tunnel vision, as a metaphor, may also denote the reluctance to consider alternatives to one's preferred line of thought; this could include physicians treating afflictions, detectives considering crime suspects, or anyone predisposed to a favoured outcome.

   We often find people focus on the offense caused by someone else without considering the motivations of the other person. Or, if motivations are considered, people sometimes [attribute the worst motivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_attribution_error) to the other person.

We can talk about this in public, if you'd like. However, I think it would be in your best interest to take a bit of time to let things cool off first.

Comment: This proves i'm right. You deny bullying exists for legal reasons only because you are staff. You couldn't lie straight in bed! http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/57/messages/1103.html